# Delete entry without deleting related entries mysql innoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, relation

I have a database where the users have different projects. A user can have multiple projects but a project can have only one user.

I get a problem if i'm going to delete a user without deleting his projects. MySql won't let me delete the user unless i first delete the projects.

Is there a way i can delete the user and keep the projects?

Comment: You can add a different column to users table, say 'active', and instead of deleting record for that user, set the value of that column to 'n' (while default value  will be 'y'). Then you can retrieve info for any project and in other parts of the app only work with users whose active column is set to 'y'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set up your schema with foreign key constraints, so the project table rows insist on the presence of the owning user.

This kind of "deletion" ïs usually done by soft deletion: by adding an "inactive" column to your tables, and setting it to "Yes" or nonzero or something like that when you want to mark a particular row as deleted.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a foreign key relationship between the tables containing users and projects, you could use this in your create table for projects table

```
 FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
 REFERENCES users(user_id)
 ON DELETE SET NULL,
```

unfortunately you need to drop and create table again, as you cant use alter to make this change on an existing table

Comment: I think you can alter a table to this. [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) supports both dropping and adding indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to alter the foreign key constraint to be able to do that. This is one of the reasons to have foreign keys, that you don't break them.